# Removing Meta boxes on Wordpress page that have been added by a theme

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

I am trying to remove some meta boxes that have been added by a theme that is installed on my Wordpress site. I am able to target an remove the wordpress ones with the code I am using but this doesnt seem to work for the ones that are being added by the theme. Is it an issue with targeting them and the code I am using isnt correct?

```
    function remove_page_metaboxes() {
       remove_meta_box('qodef-meta-box-page_general','page','normal' );

    add_action('admin_init','remove_page_metaboxes', 12);
```

When i inspect the code I can see the meta boxes are within these two divs, the standard wordpress and ones being added by plugins are going into 'normal-sortables' and if I use the same code with the correct ID they are able to be removed. But cant target the ones within the 'advanced-sortables'.

```
<div id="postbox-container-2" class="postbox-container">
<div id="normal-sortables" class="meta-box-sortables ui-sortable">
<div id="advanced-sortables" class="meta-box-sortables ui-sortable">
```

Am I missing something very obvious or is this not the correct way to remove these?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You'll have to use `advanced` as context value instead of passing `normal` as context value.

Comment: @VijayHardaha tried this also but still not having any luck...

Comment: Try with `do_meta_boxes` hook.

Comment: @VijayHardaha Getting thrown back a PHP error using this, maybe I'm writing it incorrectly but using Wordpress Codex code directly...